# Simple relational database in java - What data structures to use?

Tags: java, database, data-structures, relational-database

I want to implement a simple in memory database using java to store two relational tables (one for NBA coaches and one for NBA teams) with the following schema:

*Coaches (Coach_ID : consists of less than 7 capital letters and two digits,

season : 4 digit year,

first_name : any reasonable English name ,

last_name : any reasonable English name,

season_win : non-negative integer,

season_loss : non-negative integer,

playoff_win : non-negative integer,

playoff_loss : non-negative integer,

team : capital letters and/or digits)*

*Teams (team_ID : capital letters and/or digits,

Location : American City name, one or two English word(s),

Name : team name, any reasonable English word,

League : one capital letter)*

My question is what data structures, that are available in java, are most appropriate for representing two tables with the above record types? My database must support adding records, querying, and other simple commands, so data structures that best facilitate these operations (adding, searching, etc.) would be most helpful.

So far I've come up with the following:

```
class Team_Record {  
} 

class Coach_Record {
}

ArrayList <Team_Record> teams;
ArrayList <Coach_Record> coaches;
```

Am I headed in the right direction or is there a better way to implement database tables?

NOTE: The database is in memory only. When the program exits, the data is lost. No data persistence required.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't `Coach` belong to a `Team` ... or can a `Coach` coach more then one team?

Comment: If persistence is not required, why are you using a database?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The first relation (table) stores data on coaches from a specific season. The second relation stores data about teams, with the coach field indicating the current coach for that team.

Comment: @Bohemian - Its an initial assignment for a database design class. I assume its to familiarize ourselves with the relational database model and provide programming practice. It supports loading large tables from text files into memory where other operations can be performed. Persistence will come later.

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. You are not the first student to implement relational tables. Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justin,

Usually databases signify that you intend to do lookup and inserts. You will need to pick the best search complexity and insert complexity data structure in this case.
To start with having a ArrayList means to search for a coach or a team you need to traverse the worst case as n where n being the total number of objects in the collection.

On the other hand, if you go by Map, since you are using in-memory database, most likely you can pass along the key to different sub modules in the program and make the searching of the Coaches and Teams easy.

When dealing with databases the key factors are searchability and insertions. Fastest way to lookup and fastest way to insert.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I looked into Maps and they seem like a good fit. One question I still have is should I maintain a separate map for each (key,value) pair? Or would it be better to maintain one map per table? For example Map that maps team keys with a structure that holds all of the values.  More along the lines of (key, record).

Comment: Consider the following table
ID|NAME|AGE|MATCHES
1|BOB|55|20
2|MARLEY|25|100

In this table Keys are 1 and 2 and the values would be of the object type.
So you will need 1 Map<Number, Person>
This can hold as many persons in it as possible.
Does it make sense? More like for each key there is a row/record.